# inverse of $y = {x}/{(1+x)^{1+ \omega}}$ with $x, \omega >0$

Tags: calculus, functions, inverse-function

I am aware that inverting polynomials is hard and that probably there isn't a way to invert the function in general.

The question is whether this function can be inverted on a certain interval, for $x, \omega > 0$.

Particularly, I claim that the function is indeed invertible for $x \in [0, 1/\omega]$. This is because if I differentiate w.r.t $x$ and set to zero, I get two roots, the positive of which is $1/\omega$.

Question is whether the function can be inverted in closed form -- i.e. in terms of elementary functions--  over this interval, giving $f^{-1}(y) : [0, \frac{1}{\omega \left(1 + 1/\omega \right)^{1+\omega}}] \to [0, 1/\omega]$.

Comment: You can certainly do it for $w$ equal to $1,2,3$ (in these cases it just involves finding the appropriate root of a quadratic, cubic or quartic).

Comment: @smcc True. Should I perhaps add that I want to do it for non-integer $\omega$?

Comment: Well, that’s not what “analytically” means to most mathematicians. I would have recommended that you say “in closed form, using only elementary functions.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$z=f(x)=\frac{x}{(1+x)^{1+\omega}}$$
and
$$x=g(z)\equiv f^{-1}(z)=\sum^\infty_{n=1}g_n\frac{z^n}{n!}$$

Easily, by Lagrange inversion theorem about $z=f(a=0)$,
$$g_n=(n+n\omega)^{\underline{n-1}}$$

Therefore,
$$f^{-1}(z)=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(n+n\omega)^{\underline{n-1}} }{(n-1)!}\frac{z^n}n=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\binom{n+n\omega}{n-1}\frac{z^n}n$$

I doubt if you can get anything neater than this.

Comment: Nice formula. Can you not use it to decide on the domain of convergence? That, after all, is OP’s question.

Comment: @Lubin I think you might misinterpreted OP’s question. However, your question is interesting. I might add it to my answer later.

Comment: I think you’re right, @Szeto.